# Does Android have something like the Apple Keychain?

Tags: android, android-studio, keychain, android-keystore

I'm using Android-studio 3.0. I'm completely beginner into android development. I'm currently working in android security for app,login user credential,authorisation.

> I need to protect my user-password safely even the cache get cleared.

I referred the below links.Am i going in the right path?If not please give your suggestions.

1) https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b

2) https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Keychain for user credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897774/android-keychain-for-user-credentials)