# how to get the telephone number in real device

Tags: android

i want to know get the number of device by telephoneManager and getLine1Number() ,it is workly well in analog machine,but in real device i donot get,could you tell me why?

in the com.android.internal.telephony inlude getLine1Number() ,how can use the inner class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Phone Number in Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

Comment: SIM card gives or not access to the number.

Comment: yes,i used this TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
  mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number(); but in the real device i donot get the number,may be SIM card not access to the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered on SO a number of times. The phone number is (possibly) stored on the SIM-card and you can get it with `TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()` however, it is not reliable. Some SIM cards don't have the phone number on them (in which case you will get `null`) and if the user changes his phone number without swapping his SIM card then you will get his old phone number.