# Send an SMS to the emulator

Tags: android

I am working on an android application and I want to send an SMS to the phone number of the phone i.e the emulator. I know there will be no real phone number for emulator, but how can I send an SMS from the phone?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

Comment: Check this [Sms Messaging in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Eclipse. Select "Emulator Control" from Window -->Show View -->Android.There will be an option called Telephony Actions. There under the Incoming number just specify a sample number.Select SMS and type the text that you want and finally click "Send"

You can try this sample app too

http://samplecodeviewer.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/SampleCodeViewer/SMSTest.zip

and check for SMSSender.java class.