# How to get a mobile number for my application using an API?

Tags: android

How do get the mobile number from an Android application? After installing the application on the mobile, I want to get the mobile number of the phone. Is there any API available in Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Phone Number in Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this has been the simplest method:

```
TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = manager.getLine1Number();
```

And then add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: I have tried this method. Actually I display that mobile number String in a Alert Box. In Emulator,Mobile Number displayed in Alert box properly.But in Device, only Empty Alert Box Displayed. What is the problem here...please help me...

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29: you will probably need the appropriate permissions to get it.