# Getting Phone Number in android

Tags: android, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Phone Number in Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

I am trying to get the phone number in android.

But it is returning null.

Here is my code.

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```

I have added in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Waiting for your reply and thanks in advance

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk It looks similar to what you have done, but note `CommonsWare`'s comment: > Also, there are reports
> that some SIMs cause this method to return null.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278/379693