# Not able to detect SIM change in android

Tags: java, android, file

Hi friends i am using the following code to detect SIM change but not able to get the result.
Please suggest me where i am making the mistake.

I am Using MainActivity.java class for Storing SIM msisdn. like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String FILENAME = "old_file.txt";
int simstatus;
String msisdn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    simstatus = tManager.getSimState();
    if (simstatus != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {
        System.out.println("--------SIM Present:" + simstatus);
        msisdn = tManager.getLine1Number();
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(msisdn.getBytes());
            System.out.println("---------Data written to files is:"
                    + msisdn);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

And for receiving the Reboot event i am using SIMTestReceiver class like this.

```
public class SIMTestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))  {
        Intent CompareSimServiceIntent = new Intent(context,TestDATAScreen.class);
        context.startService(CompareSimServiceIntent);
    }

}
```

And for comparing the old SIM and New SIM i am using TestDATAScreen service class like this.

```
public class TestDATAScreen extends Service {

String FILENAME = "old_file.txt";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String data = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("---Data Read From File is:" + data);
        String newsiminfo = tManager.getLine1Number();
        System.out.println("---New SIM no is:" + newsiminfo);
        if (data.equals(tManager.getLine1Number())) {
            System.out.println("------Old sim Present:");

            Toast.makeText(this, "Old SIM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "New SIM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SmsManager smsMngr = SmsManager.getDefault();
            String destinationaddress = "8689908070";
            String scAddress = null;
            String text = "New Sim Is Inserted In Your Device";
            PendingIntent sentIntent = null;
            PendingIntent deliveryIntent = null;
            smsMngr.sendTextMessage(destinationaddress, scAddress, text,
                    sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
            System.out.println("-----SMS Send");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return startId;

}
```

Comment: How are you detecting the sim details

Comment: Yes.i am able to detect SIM details.

Comment: @Rakshi By using this TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String serial = tManager.getLine1Number();

Comment: I am using the Above permission also.                                 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Comment: To detect sim changes you have to store the previous value somewhere and every time you have check if its same or its changed, Is this the way you are doing it

Comment: Yes @Rakshi I am using a txt file to save these data please look in to my activity class.

Comment: I find a suitable Answer [here][1] which resolve my issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278/872565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually comparing serial number using `tManager.getSimSerialNumber()` Solve my issue. AS  There is no guaranteed result from `tManager.getLine1Number()`to this problem because the phone number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards, or broadcasted from the network to the phone.

Answer (score 1):

You first save the sim and then compare the saved sim with the current sim. You never load the old sim's serialnumber.

Comment: Yes. But you overwrite the old serial with the new serial. Before you load the old serial. You should save the new serial after you loaded the old one.