# how to get phone number if my phone number is not set to phone setting

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Phone Number in Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

I want to read my phone number I had tried this:

```
TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   phoneNumber = manager.getLine1Number();
```

But it returns null. In my setting->about phone->phone number also it shows unknown.

Then how to read own phone number in android.

Any suggestion will be appreciated,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this tutorial for [How to Get Own Mobile Number Programmatically](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-get-own-mobile-number.html)

Please read all the information I have written below tutorial there

> As I have read, so far some people have conflict about different
>   behavior of  output. There are reports that some SIMs cause this
>   method to return null.
>
> Because There is no guaranteed solution to this problem because the phone
>   number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards, or broadcasted from
>   the network to the phone. This is especially  true in some countries
>   which requires physical address verification, with number assignment
>   only happening afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding the permission READ_PHONE_STATE to the manifest file.

Comment: I had added permission already.

Comment: See the reply by johan in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk