# How to get Mobile number using Flex 4.6 Mobile Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.6, flex-mobile

This is Bhanu Teja. I am new to Flex mobile application. Can any one let me know, "How to get the mobile number in our flex mobile application". I am using Flex 4.6.

Thanks & Regards
Bhanu Teja M.

Comment: If you mean the phone number; AIR does not explicitly expose this.  If the underlying operating system makes it available then you can create a Native Extension to expose it.  For some reason I didn't think that iOS made that information available via APIs; but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On IOS it is not possible, the API is private and Apple will reject your app if you do it

On Android you will have to write a native extension to accomplish this.  From there Android has an API to get it.  This answer details how to get the phone number from android natively

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480307/731880