# How to access to phone number?

Tags: android

How can I build android application be able to access to the user's phone number when you download this application then i retrieve this number ?
 For Example:

```
 public class Phonenumber  
 {
      //functions 
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very simple to get user phone number .

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Required

```
permission READ_PHONE_STATE in android manifest file.
```

Comment: thanxx alot but where i put TelephonyManager ,, In onCreat ??

Comment: Yes, you can but after setContentView() method.

Comment: hi MR.Chirag Raval ,,, This Function didn't work ,,, You can help me

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);      

String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Requires permission `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

Add below part in android manifest xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: hi  This Function didn't work ,,, You can help me

Comment: what you have tried ? update question with your code.

Comment: Hi,

unfortunality not all Carrier are saving the own phone number on
the sim card. The carrier O2 e.g don`t do that.

So i can`t get the own phone number with the TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() Value in any case !

Is there any other possibility to find out the own phone number in really any case ? 

I thought about an USSD command, e.g. *#62# to receive the answer from the carrier, but
unfortunality Android dosn`t have an API for USSD   

So, it would be very nice if somebody give me a hint to solve this problem !

Thanx a lot and withe best regards

Comment: `Intent dial = new Intent(); dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL"); dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+dial_number)); startActivity(dial);`
you can use this to execute USSD commands. in your case `dial_number` is ***#62#**.

Answer (score 1):

you can use TelePhonyManager.getLineNumber() as other suggested. But I should add one thing. That this is not gurranteed for every operator to get the telephone number by this method. because the phone number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards, or broadcasted from the network to the phone. So in some network it may not return the number. So to me the best solution is to ask user to enter telephone number if you want to make your application global.

Moreover it is a duplicate question. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278/931982.

Comment: nice ,, but سome users have the fear of put their numbers

Comment: yes I know that is a pain. But it is better than getting nothing. See in some cases there is a possibility of not getting the number. I think you can do one thing. first try to get the number then if not possible then prompt for input.

Comment: Yes, I also thought of this idea, thank you very much