# Get phonenumber programmatically - Android

Tags: android, phone-number

is it possible to get the phonenumber of each device programmatically?
I tried this code:

```
TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = manager.getLine1Number();
```

This works fine with some providers. Unfortunately it does not work with each provider. So i am looking for a trick or work around to get the phonenumber of the device. Is there a solution or is it impossible because the number is not stored on the sim card?

Comment: Hi, Did you get solution to find the phone number will all carriers, Can you please share me your solution ? Thank you

Comment: I can tell you that it is not possible. Some providers do not store the phonenumber on SIM card. So you might ask the user to enter the phonenumber and verify it with a sms and BroadcastReceiver. This is the only alternative I have found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method you are using is the only one part of the SDK to do this, and only works on devices where the number is stored  on the SIM card, which only some carriers do. For all other carriers, you will have to ask the user to enter the phone number manually, as the number is simply not stored anywhere on the device from where you can retrieve it.

Comment: I guess that the number will not be stored in the log (e.g. as the sender of a sms)?

Comment: @JavaForAndroid No, it isn't.

Comment: See the following for a broader discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-number-of-the-android-phone-with-the-api#comment2472240_2480307

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send specific SMS to ISP.
For example, in Beijing(China), when you send SMS "501" to 10001, you will get your phone number in the received message. 
Then you only need to know how to send SMS and register a BroadcastReceiver to receive the message.

Comment: @Billa Dec yes~~

Answer (score 0):

Now its not require any permission to get phone number
use Play Services API without the permission and hacks. [Source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/effective-phone-number-verification.html) and [Full example.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/ui/PhoneNumberActivity.java)

build.gradle (version 10.2.x and higher required):

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$gms_version"
```

In your activity (the code is simplified):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP4ng.png)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// ...
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
        .build();
requestPhoneNumber(result -> {
    phoneET.setText(result);
});
}

public void requestPhoneNumber(SimpleCallback<String> callback) {
phoneNumberCallback = callback;
HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
        .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
        .build();

PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(googleApiClient, 
hintRequest);
try {
    startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(), PHONE_NUMBER_RC, null, 
0, 0, 0);
} catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
    Logs.e(TAG, "Could not start hint picker Intent", e);
}
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == PHONE_NUMBER_RC) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Credential cred = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
        if (phoneNumberCallback != null){
            phoneNumberCallback.onSuccess(cred.getId());
        }
    }
    phoneNumberCallback = null;
}
}
```