# Any way to Get Phone No. from Sim to Android Application Automatically

Tags: android

i working on android Application and i want to get **Only phone Number** Not IMSI or IMEI No. 
from sim card (or)  Mobile Phone to my Android application.

if i use getLine1Number() function from  TelephonyManager

it will return null because setting/aboutPhone/PhoneNumber is "Unknown" in almost all

any Possible way ??

please help me !

Answer (score 1):

According to this good explained answer, there is no other way of retrieving the phone number if it is unknown (not stored in the SIM card).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17296286/1943671

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, please remember that not all Android devices are phones.