# how to check whether mobile number is active on device or not?

Tags: android, mobile

I am developing an app in which I have to do is that when user enter his/her mobile number ,first check that entered mobile number is active on that device or not if active then move to next if not active on that device that show a toast message.kindly help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get phonenumber programmatically - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296252/get-phonenumber-programmatically-android)

Comment: another possible duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone

Answer (score 1):

Mobile number verification is done using SMS OTP.
There are various service providers which you can use or develop your own service.

https://docs.nexmo.com/api-ref/verify

https://cognalys.com/