# how to get mobile number automatically in android application resistration like whatsapp

Tags: android

How can I get mobile number automatically soon after user installs my android application. When registered in my application without entering manually. I am using the following code.

```
TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = manager.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the permission READ_PHONE_STATE in manifest

also please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk) for more information!