# How would you implement an unregistered login?

Tags: android, authentication

For example, if I use this code shown in this answer:
[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

Is it technically possible for a user to fake that number?

I'm thinking about developing an app which uses telephone number as unique id, as if it were an username.

What do you think guys?

What is around my head, is to find out a way to make users "login" to a webservice but without any register. Though about IMEI or Telephone number, but I think both of them can be faked. Also they could trace the webservice's url and fake the POST info sent.

Maybe the best solution is OAUTH auth from facebook / google / twitter?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both IMEI and phone number can be faked. If you want to use phone number you can send an sms to this number with a verification code and the application will check if the code is correct. This is what Whatsapp and other application do.

Comment: I guess i should then use something like fb or twitter auth.