# Device Phone Number

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I need a way to capture an Android device's phone number in order to send it back to my web api for processing.

I've read about the issues and [inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone#comment-2472240) with the [getLine1Number](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()) function so my question is this, are there any programmatic alternatives to  `getLine1Number` or is it the only available method to retrieve the device phone number?

To be clear, I am not looking for a UUID, this is a mobile phone application and I require the users phone number for data association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getLine1Number () for this. It will returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.

here is an example:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

It requires the READ_PHONE_STATE permission to be added on the Androidmanifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippets of code to get phone numbers:

```
....
private final static String PHONE = "phone";
...

Map<String, String> contactDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri contactData = data.getData();
    //Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor =  cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    contactDataMap.put(NAME, (name != null)?name:"");


    if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                null, 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                                new String[]{id},
                                null);

        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
            String number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            contactDataMap.put(PHONE, (number != null)?number:"");
            break; // ? we want only 1 value
        } 
        pCur.close();
    }
```

By this way you can fetch phone numbers. be sure that you have permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: I think that he is looking for a way to detect the phone number not to retrieve contact list.