# How can get details of user who install or download my app

Tags: mobile

I have develop my app using `PhoneGap`.

When End User downloads or installs an application on his/her mobile, I need to retrieve his details like email & mob no.

My question is:

a) Does `Google Play` provides any API by which we can retrieve details on every day basis?

b) As soon as user  download or install app,  can we able to retrieve details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically obtain the number of the Android phone with the API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-number-of-the-android-phone-with-the-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this will be good solution. After installation of your application just allow  the user for registration from your client app by registering the mobile details(model number, Version,UUID) along with user details (email id, phone number)then send these details to your server using RESTwebservice or servlet (its ur wish) and stored in your database. By default Phonegap API, allows to retrieve the device hardware and software details. Link [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device).

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user to give them to you. Don't try and take their details without their permission.

Comment: we are taking users permission to get thier personal details