# How can I get my own phone number programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I tried the following code to get my own number and get a NULL string. What is the problem?

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;     
 mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     
 String phoneNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing/5134725#5134725/

Answer (score 3):

Use  [TelephonyManager.**getLine1Number()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29)

**But you need to have stored the phone number on the SIM card**, and there´s no other way to get your "own number".

Example:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String myPhoneNumber =  tm.getLine1Number();
```

and you need this permission into your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

See this Question:
[TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing)
as describe, you need to evaluate:

```
if("SIM card present" && "phone number is stored") {
  "get the phone number with TelephonyManager.getLine1Number"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

You need the user's permission to retrieve this data

If it still returns null, that means the data is not available, and you cant use it.

See [Get my phone number in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894080/get-my-phone-number-in-android)

Comment: I've added the permission but still same problem