# How to get my phone number?

Tags: android, sms, phone-number

I need to get device phone number.

I'm aware of

```
 TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

However I know, that this method may generate wrong results.

My second idea was to send SMS message to myself. I'll get message with broadcast receiver, read number and then `abortBroadcast();`
Yeah... but how to send message to myself without knowing my phone number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894080/get-my-phone-number-in-android

Comment: Are you calling this from outside the Activity class?