# Unable to get phone number from a dual sim

Tags: android

Unable to get phone number from mobile-:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
        Log.i("Log", "Phone no is -: "+mPhoneNumber);
        myContactNo.setText(mPhoneNumber);
```

I am not getting the phone number and it is empty. I have added permission in Android Manifest.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889

Comment: Most of the carrier provider disabled this function

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

**In AndroidManifest.xml, write the following permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894080/get-my-phone-number-in-android)