# getting phone number of a device in android

Tags: android

hey guys im trying to get phone number of my cell phone using android studio

i have entered permissions in the manifest file i.e.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and the code im using is

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String m=tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

but when i run my run my app it crashes. i m unable to resolve this problem.
kindly help me out. thanks!

the problem is with the statement

```
String m=tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.umk.stylefeedback, PID: 32333
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.umk.stylefeedback/com.example.umk.stylefeedback.NumberConfirmation}: java.lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10097 nor current process has android.permission.READ_SMS.
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10097 nor current process has android.permission.READ_SMS.
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getLine1NumberForDisplay(ITelephony.java:3731)
                                                                                   at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getLine1NumberForSubscriber(TelephonyManager.java:2101)
                                                                                   at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getLine1Number(TelephonyManager.java:2079)
                                                                                   at com.example.umk.stylefeedback.NumberConfirmation.onCreate(NumberConfirmation.java:35)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Can you add crash logs?

Comment: Bear in mind that `getLine1Number()` does not have to return the user's phone number.

Comment: I think phone numbers are stored in SIM cards. you can only get serial number.

Comment: @CommonsWare always correct. Please look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894080/get-my-phone-number-in-android

Comment: im new in here dont know how to add crash logs. :/

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the logs and look for the Java stack trace associated with your crash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this. You can then click the "edit" link under your question, paste in the Java stack trace, and format it as source (as you did some of the other lines in your question).

Comment: @CommonsWare so how can i get the phone number automatically? im new to android development.

Comment: Please try the ways given in comments and ask questions later.

Comment: ```java.lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10097 nor current process has android.permission.READ_SMS.``` points out that you are missing at least the ```READ_SMS``` permission.

Answer (score 3):

Hello can share logcat.

There is no guaranteed solution to this problem because the phone number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards, or broadcasted from the network to the phone. This is especially true in some countries which requires physical address verification, with number assignment only happening afterwards. Phone number assignment happens on the network - and can be changed without changing the SIM card or device (e.g. this is how porting is supported).

I know it is pain, but most likely the best solution is just to ask the user to enter his/her phone number once and store it.

Comment: and how can i import contacts in to my app?

Comment: it crashes even importing contacts

Comment: Umair , As your word you want to copy all contact of Phonebook ..? i m right  .?

Answer (score 1):

Umair,

You can copy all phonebook contact and insert own app db

```
 public void fetchContacts() {
        ////Log.e("step ", "1");
        String phoneNumber, phonetype = null;

        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Loop for every contact in the phone
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));

                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                            , new String[]{contact_id}, DISPLAY_NAME);
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        String string = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                        // String where2 = childJSONObject.getString("phone_number");
                        if (string.length() > 10)
                            string = string.substring(string.length() - 10);
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        if (ValidationUtil.isValidMobileNumber(string)) {
                            if (string.length() > 2) {
                                try {
                                    object.put("name", helper.ConvertCamel(name));
                                    object.put("phone", Long.parseLong(string.trim()));
                                    objects.add(object);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```