# Location of Android device phone number

Tags: android, sqlite

So on an Android device, one can navigate to Settings > About Phone > Status and find the device's phone number.

Where is this information stored in the Android databases for, say, an SDK emulated device?  I know I can use the telephony manager, but I'd like to know where to find it using SQLite.

I realize I can find it programatically, but is there any way to do it with just SQLite?

I'm fairly new to Android, so forgive me if this is a bad question.  It seems like the device phone number should be stored somewhere sensible, but at this point I'm not terribly optimistic.

P.S. Please notice, I am not asking how to retreive it (which is duplicate with other questions). I am asking, where it's actually stored.

Comment: An emulated device is not going to have a telephone number.

Comment: Never mind an emulated device will have a fake number.

Answer (score 0):

The platform settings app uses the same `TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()` call as mentioned in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-number-of-the-android-phone-with-the-api):

```
String rawNumber = mPhone.getLine1Number();  // may be null or empty
String formattedNumber = null;
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rawNumber)) {
    formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(rawNumber);
}
// If formattedNumber is null or empty, it'll display as "Unknown".
setSummaryText(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, formattedNumber);
```

(From [src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/Status.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/deviceinfo/Status.java))