# Programmatically getting Null or Blank device's Phone number in some devices

Tags: android

I have tried below code

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

I have tried in two device

1. Micromax Canvas-4 (Getting user phone number)
2. Htc desire 816G (Not able to get user phone number)

Please help me !!
Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is occurring because you need to set your own phone number on the device.
please have a look at the below link.

[getLine1Number() Returns blank, not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497766/getline1number-returns-blank-not-null)

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I checked you given link but it is not solution it is just need to set default value in phone number if i did not get through the code. But my question is why we got Null/Blank Phone number even if device has Sim card

Comment: getLine1Number() only get the number stored on the sim card..a lot of operators don't write the sim number.............. please check below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing