# Why the getLine1Number() method is imperceptible in android

Tags: android

Please see the following simple code. I want to display the `getLine1Number()` method in the `textView`, because the return value from the method is as `String`.
But when I run the code in my device, the result is imperceptible.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String s = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
 textView.setText(s);}
 }
```

And

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing)

Comment: I'm sure this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21497906/5230201