# How to uniquely identify SIM

Tags: android

I want to uniquely identify Sim, but if I am using `TelephonyManager getLine1Number()` it always return null, if I am using `TelephonyManager getDeviceId()` it is returned even without sim. So the question is that how can I uniquely identify SIM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getLine1Number() Returns blank, not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497766/getline1number-returns-blank-not-null)

Comment: The device ID for a GSM phone identifies the phone. AFAIK, `getSubscriberId()`, which returns the IMSI, identifies the subscriber.