# Sending GCM push notification to a particular phone using its phone number(the device that has this phone number installed my app. )

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was searching this for the last 2 days but I cannot find any answer. All what I want is to send GCM push notification to a particular phone using its phone number instead of register id(of course the device that has this phone number installed my app. ).
Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to send GCM by phone number.

Comment: GCM doesn't use phone numbers, as it also needs to work on tablets which are connected to the outside world via wifi only.

Comment: Is'nt there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM does not use or register phone numbers. You could possibly assign a UserID of some kind on install, perform a PUSH that results in data sent to your server with all those ID's so that you can connect to a phone number - but there's no reliable way to guarantee that you have the correct device phone number unless the user enters it.

[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-number-of-the-android-phone-with-the-api)

GCM does not use the phone number (and probably Google does not want it). That's typically called "SMS" or "MMS"

Comment: Is'nt there a better workaround other than make users assign and send the phone back to the server?

Comment: Workaround? It isn't clear why you care about the phone number. You only need that for phone services (calls, SMS, MMS). Unless you want to do those things - in which case have the device send your gateway an SMS with an ID as its content...