# I can't get phone number in my android app

Tags: android, phone-number

I tried lots of things as you said here.But there is no output when i tested the code.I also changed my manifest to allow permission also.Here is my code :

`TelephonyManager tMenager= (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    simId=tMenager.getSimSerialNumber();
    telephoneNumber=tMenager.getLine1Number();
    Imei=tMenager.getDeviceId();`

```
Log.d("Telefon Numarası !!!!! :",telephoneNumber);

textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefonno);
textView.setText("Phone No :"+telephoneNumber);
```

Comment: in manifest :

 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2480307

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get phone no of device programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675868/how-to-get-phone-no-of-device-programmatically)