# how to get mobile number from my current Phone? it's display blank Mobile Number in Log. but when run on emulator its display emulator Number

Tags: android

```
public class MobileNumber extends Activity {

    TextView mobNO;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.mobile_number);
        mobNO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMobNO);

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String getSimSerialNumber = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
        String getOperatorName = tm.getSimOperatorName();
        String getNetworkCountry = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
        String getDeviceSoftVersion = tm.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();
        String getDeviceId = tm.getDeviceId();

        if (tm.getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {

            String mPhoneNumber = tm.getLine1Number();

            String mobilenumber = mPhoneNumber.substring(Math.max(
                    mPhoneNumber.length() - 10, 0));

            Log.e("My Number is:-", "-------" + "  " + mobilenumber);
            Log.e("My Operator Name is:- ", "*******" + "  " + getOperatorName);
            Log.e("My Sim is:-", "******* " + "  " + getSimSerialNumber);
            Log.e("My Network Country is:-", "*******" + "  "
                    + getNetworkCountry);
            Log.e("My Device Software Version:-", "*******" + "  "
                    + getDeviceSoftVersion);
            Log.e("My Device Id is.:-", "-------" + "  " + getDeviceId);

            mobNO.setText(mobilenumber);

        } else {

            Log.e("no sim card", "...");

        }

    }

}
```

Output

```
--------------------------------------------OUTPUT----------------------------------------------------
09-08 14:17:24.618: E/My Number is:-(1206): -------
09-08 14:17:24.618: E/My Operator Name is:-(1206): *******  Android
09-08 14:17:24.618: E/My Sim is:-(1206): *******   89014103211118510720
09-08 14:17:24.618: E/My Network Country is:-(1206): *******  us
09-08 14:17:24.618: E/My Device Software Version:-(1206): *******  null
09-08 14:17:24.618: E/My Device Id is.:-(1206): -------  000000000000000
```

Comment: Not all SIM cards provide the MSISDN number. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-number-of-the-android-phone-with-the-api?lq=1

Comment: so what can i do?? i'm put above code but can't get mobile number..

Comment: i'm tried different network provider sim cards. but just got blank.

Comment: Yes, that's just how it works.

Comment: just got blank. i know above code is perfect but i dont know what's the problem.. :(

Comment: in Short number only displaying in those cell phone whose display cell number in Setting/about phone/status/my mobile number then we can directly got a number from cell phone to application.