# Getting user phone number in Android

Tags: android, phone-number, telephonymanager

Is there any way to retrieve a phone number in Android without using the TelephonyManager?

Because if the phone operator is blocking the number, then this solution fails. 
Solutions such as this one fails to retrieve the user's phone number: [How to get phone number android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376050/how-to-get-phone-number-android-phone)

Comment: Implement OTP functionality.

Comment: Nope. Android does not allow to get phone number without permission and only way to get the number is Telephony Manager.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Comment: @YourJavaMinion i think you didnt noticed he asked `without using the TelephonyManager?`

Comment: Did you read all the answers?

Comment: I feel this is a hack but if it suits your use case you can use the `send sms permission` and use the SmsManager API to send a message to predefined number where you can read the same. This is workaround for not using the telephony manager.