# Why i am not getting the current sim card number in android?

Tags: java, android, gsm

I tried :

```
 TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
 String simnumber = tm.getLine1Number();
```

It returns number from (Aboutus-settings-phonenumber)

But i want to get the data from  from simcard not from phone settings

I read many Forums Like below  But i couldn't found the solution

[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/how-can-i-programmatically-obtain-the-number-of-the-android-phone-with-the-api)

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: It returns null value

Comment: Maybe you have to enable some permission.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: My Question is i can read the data from phone setting ., but i want from sim card .is it possible

Comment: It seems not possible. But you can get sim serial number.

Comment: @Amol Tate where the sim numbers  are stored  (is it from particular sim server like bsnl)

Comment: You have store it manually in phone setting

Comment: is there any way to get the mobile number from (Message center) http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-send-sms-in-android