# Send variables from google play store to application

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am sending SMS to users with a link to my app's listing in Google Play Store. Once the user downloads the application, he/she needs to enter their phone number for signup.

Since I already have users phone numbers when I send them the SMS invitation, is there any way I can send them to a special link from the SMS message that will contain their phone number, and then it will somehow pass from the play store to my application?

That way, users who downloaded the app via SMS link to play store, will not need to enter their phone numbers upon signup.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar The user will be shown the phone number and approve it before signup occurs... As for deep linking, this is the case when the app is already installed. In my case, I want to receive data from the app store

Comment: Well this not seems possible!

Answer (score 1):

Try the INSTALL_REFERRER provided by google. [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver)

With the help of the INSTALL_REFERRER you can actually pass data from the playstore to the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the phone number from the Android API, there is no use for it to be retrieved from outside:

[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Answer (score 0):

Since March 2020, this is no longer supported and you have to use the new API provided by Google https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library