# How can i plot the lat ,lng sent from my android app to tomcat server and plot on the google maps there?

Tags: java, android, tomcat, servlets, jsp-tags

please be a support, i have sent the lat/lngs obtained from my android to an apache tomcat server,running java for web using servlets and jsps. I wont to plot those obtained lat/lngs on the Google maps. can any body please tell me how should and can i do that.
*Using servlets and jsps
Thanks tons in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Comment: Please do not change a question once it has been answered. If you need a different answer, please ask a new question instead of modifying this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this. but some reason all mobile provider not give mobile number.

mobile no

```
public String getPhoneNO() {
    String phoneno = "";
    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    phoneno = tMgr.getLine1Number();
    if (phoneno != null) {
        return phoneno;
    }
    return "";
}
```

// Sim

```
public String getSim() {
    String phoneno = "";
    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    phoneno = tMgr.getSimOperatorName();
    if (phoneno != null) {
        return phoneno;
    }
    return "";
}
```