# Cannot retrieve whatsapp contact's numbers

Tags: android, whatsapp, android-cursor

This is my code for getting whatsapp contacts but i can't getting contact numbers. My code is:
hatsApp it's "com.whatsapp". So:

```
   Cursor c =       getContentResolver().query(
    RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] {    RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
    RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
    new String[] { "com.whatsapp" },
    null);

 ArrayList<String> myWhatsappContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
   int contactNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        myWhatsappContacts.add(c.getString(contactNameColumn));
    }
```

Tried both Contacts and Contacts.Data but it is only showing only names . Can anybody help me please?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17121105/548395) answer, WhatsApp stopped sharing phone numbers.

Comment: I mean i need my whatsapp contact numbers