# How to get phone number of the device in android activity

Tags: java, android, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

Is there any way to get phone number of device, by using GoogleApiClient. I got email, now want phone number.

Comment: No, not possible using GoogleApiClient.  There is one way you can do it, but it's flaky and doesn't always work, see here: [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

and later use this:

```
TelephonyManager t = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = t.getLine1Number();
```

**Note:** This method - although one of the only ways to do it - is not reliable. It can return a false number, blank string, or even `null`.

Comment: Not copy, i do this in my app a few days.

Comment: Some device can not get phone number!

Comment: Don't forget that you'll need to ask for permission

Comment: I am getting null? what is the problem?

Comment: Sad, dont work for me, testing on Honor 9, and Sony Xperia