# After WhatsApp phone number confirmation is it possible to get the confirmed number programatically?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying to get the confirmed phone number from whatsApp programatically. I saw a lot of questions regarding the problem that exist to get the number from the phone.

Like this one here: [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

However all this questions say that this is not the perfect way to do it because in some phones it will not work. You can see a lot of people saying that in any of those questions.

**The second option** is to use a 3rd part service like Twilio and Nexmo and go through the confirmation process all the way exactly like WhatsApp does:
- Ask to user to type the number
- Send and SMS
- Confirm user phone

I have been thinking about the existence of a **third option**: get the phone that is already confirmed and saved in WhatsApp.

Once I checked WhatsApp FAQ and found that they are really helpful. For example, I found this information about how to use their API to send stuff. You can check it here: [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012)

Although I didn't find nothing about how to get the WhatsApp number from the user phone.

I am just wondering if some of you have already tried it or had success trying to get this confirmed number. I believe that it will save tons of times of anyone who plans to use phone numbers as ID's for their apps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think WhatsApp will provide his user personal information to 3rd parties.

You need to ask yourself from user. After that its user choice he provides his information or not.

Read WhatsApp [Legal Policy](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/)

> You agree not to collect or harvest any personally identifiable
>   information, including **phone number**, from the Service, nor to use the
>   communication systems provided by the Service for any commercial
>   solicitation or spam purposes. You agree not to spam, or solicit for
>   commercial purposes, any users of the Service.