# Getting the number of the phone Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I found out that this code shared by some users doesn't work in my project. Has anyone a better solution ?

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

I'm getting an error on the `getLine1Number()` and on the `mAppContext`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "mAppContext does not exist in the current context" and "TelephonyManager does not contain a defenition for GetLine1Number()"

Comment: @LuisViolas : Your code is in native Android (Java). You must use Xamarin.Android (C#). Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36034077/3891036

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` to manifest?

It's not really perfect, but the only way (at least to my knowledge). Broader discussion is here [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone#comment2472240_2480307)