# How to get the phone number in xamarin forms signup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

```
var tMgr = (TelephonyManager)Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
     return tMgr.Line1Number;
```

This code is returning null.

I want to generate this type of popup while registration
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbN3j.png)

Comment: Where do you call the method ?Could you show more codes about it ?I  could get the phone number correctly in MainActivity with the method.

Comment: Hello, Please refere this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068889/xamarin-forms-display-the-phone-number-of-my-sim-card-at-device-on-the-screen .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , we need to add the permission in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

In Addition ,  `Forms.Context` is obsolete after XF 2.5 . So we could use the plugin [Plugin.CurrentActivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) from nuget.

Simply call the Init method on **OnCreate** in MainActivity

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
```

And access it like following

```
var tMgr = (TelephonyManager)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
 return tMgr.Line1Number;
```

Comment: This is not working. it is returning a blank value.

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side directly ?

Comment: Please share your email?

Comment: You could share it to github andshare the link .