# how to Obtain mobile number android

Tags: android

I used this code for fetching the number, But it gave me null

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch the existing mobile number?

Comment: It doesn't always return the mobile number, so sometimes it can return null. All is depends of the network provider that provide the mobile number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Answer (score 0):

It may not always return mobile number.

Let me explain how this actually works: When you buy a new SIM card for a new number, the provider had already (though not always) put a mobile number in the SIM (SIM Cards do have a little memory). Now `TelephonyManager` API tries to read that number. If it is available then it returns the number.

Now, you can get a SIM without a mobile number associated with it. Example - new SIM for porting (where you use previous number in new SIM Card). Those SIMs don't have any number stored on them, and hence `TelephonyManager` returns null.

Now, even if `TelephonyManager` returns a number, you **should not** trust it to be right. Because many devices provide option to edit that number.

Answer (score 0):

To use [`getLine1Number()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()) you need either `READ_PHONE_STATE` OR `READ_SMS` permission. You may be missing that.

And remember that it returns `null` if phone number string is unavailable.

Comment: i gave those permissions.  but it still return null value.

Comment: settings>>about phone>>status>>phone number  is unavailable

Comment: So that you are getting `null`. Did you get it. You have to find out why it's unavailable. Your codes are fine.