# How to fetch device's mobile number programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, xml

This code is not working...It giving null...

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)HomeActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

Log.e("Mobile No. :",""+mPhoneNumber);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mPhoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: try in other device

Comment: add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> in menifest

Comment: I already added it. but its not working.

Comment: I tested it in letv 1s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23675998/6756514

Comment: Not working. I still getting null value...

Comment: bija phone ma try kar

Comment: hope this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone

Comment: I got it.sim no number sim details ma nato nakhelo etle null madtu tu.Thanx Divyesh.

Comment: Can I get 2nd sim's number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got result by using of below code,

```
TelephonyManager telephonyMananger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mobNumber = telephonyMananger.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for it:

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

and you also have to add "READ_PHONE_STATE" permission in Androidmanifest.xml file.

and if you are testing the app on higher OS device then you also have to ask for the permission externally.

hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check in Phone--> Settings --> About --> Phone identity If you are able to view the number  then you will get phone number otherwise won't able to get number