# Use Android Payment Api to verify real identity and home address

Tags: android, api, payment

Do you know if there is a way to use Google Android Payment Api to get real info about the user, like phone number, billing address and verified payment methods?

Answer (score 0):

Check FullWallet class :

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/FullWallet

To get user billing address :

**getBuyerBillingAddress ()**

To get payment methods :

**getInstrumentInfos ()**

**getPaymentDescriptions ()**

Getting phone number is tricky. More details in this thread :

[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Comment: Dont judge me, but I dont undertand how to create a wallet and how to implement the api. I've alredy set up authentication with google sig in and firebase. Once I get the user id and token what should I do in order to set the wallet api?

Comment: Do I have to request a payment in order to get address and know if the user has a verified payment method? I would like to be as less invasive as possible

Comment: I think it's not possible. It is a great missing feature