# Obtain the phone number of the phone WITHOUT country prefix

Tags: android, phone-number, telephonymanager

To pre-fill a phone-number field in our application we'd like to use the SIM-stored phone number (when available). For this we used the common solution also outlined [in this popular question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone):

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

The issue with this, however, is that this string will also contain the **international dialing prefix**, i.e. will look something like this:

```
'+[prefix][phoneNumber]'
```

As the `prefix` varies [between 1 and 3 digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes), it's we can't simply trim it...

--> **Is there a way to get to the phone number from the SIM *without* the country dialing prefix?**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number with [libphonenumber-android](http://libphonenumber-android), something like this:

```
PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(getApplicationContext());

try {
  // Indonesia phone number
  final Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = util.parse("+62821234567", "ID");

  // now you get the number without country code
  long nationalNumber = phoneNumber.getNationalNumber();
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I haven't tested the code though.