# How to get phone number programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I want to programmatically get the phone number in Android Studio.
I've tried this: (and it is causing crashes)

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =          
      (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 


String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

What is wrong? Any other ways to get the phone number?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Comment: Please post the logs with error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

```
private String getMyPhoneNO() {
    TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
    return mPhoneNumber;
}
```

with

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    } else {
        String phoneNumber = getMyPhoneNO();
    }
```

in Activity/Fragment

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String phoneNumber = getMyPhoneNO();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`
to manifest + request the permission on runtime for newer android versions.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
}
```

Otherwise you can see a explaining error in the stacktrace.