# Programmatically Get phone number in Android

Tags: android

In my Android application, I need to display phone numbers of the Sim cards which are available in the device.

I tried with the below codes

```
 private String getPhone() {
    TelephonyManager phoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, wantPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return "";
    }
    return phoneMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```

and

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
List<SubscriptionInfo> subscription = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext()).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
for (int i = 0; i < subscription.size(); i++) {
    SubscriptionInfo info = subscription.get(i);
    Log.d(TAG, "number " + info.getNumber());
    Log.d(TAG, "network name : " + info.getCarrierName());
    Log.d(TAG, "country iso " + info.getCountryIso());
}
```

}

But both are returning null or empty string only.

I have added the manifest permission also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Could you please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you cant get phone number from android. there are some sp are allowing read phone number, but most of are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Comment: This only returns the number if it is stored on the sim card. or else it's null

Comment: here is the best response to getting phone number
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278/3999469

Answer (score 0):

some phone companies not give this permission to get number from sim-card because i was same problem in past projects.

(in the past project i want to send OTP on simcard number user can't type his  number. it was for security purpose.)
so some of phone gives you output correct and remains give you output as NULL