# Android get Telephone Number

Tags: android, phone-number

I try to get the phone number with this function but it returns a empty string. 
Can anyone help me?

```
private String getPhoneNumber(){
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
        mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return mTelephonyManager.getLine1Number();
    }
```

On create:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo6);

                mP.setNumber(getPhoneNumber());
                Log.i("number",mp.getNumber());


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It always return empty. go to `Settings > About Phone > Status > My Phone Number` If you find your number there then only you will get number by this method.

Comment: Show us the logcat.

Comment: Please refer to [this answer on the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278).