# checking for an explicit permission?

Tags: java, android

> in my code the permission log will be display but the phone number is not visible in toast
>   **how to get simcard number in the toast message with the use of explicit permission**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String TAG = "PhoneActivityTAG";
Activity activity = MainActivity.this;
String wantPermission = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (!checkPermission(wantPermission)) {
        requestPermission(wantPermission);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Phone number: " + getPhone());
    }

}

private String getPhone() {
    TelephonyManager phoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, wantPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "my phone no is:-" + phoneMgr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return phoneMgr.getLine1Number();
}

private void requestPermission(String permission){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Phone state permission allows us to get phone number. Please allow it for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Phone number: " + getPhone());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity,"Permission Denied. We can't get phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission(String permission){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

please help me
how can i get phone number in the display toast?

Comment: You are trying to display object in toast!! and i would suggest you to refactor your permission code. this is not the good way.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the answer written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone).

some correction in code

```
private String getPhone() {
    TelephonyManager phoneMgr = (TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, wantPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "my phone no is:-" + phoneMgr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return phoneMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```