# How can I get the device phone number using device info in react-native in case of "Dual SIM"

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-device-info

If the mobile has Dual SIM card How can I get the device phone number using device info in react-native?
I have added **READ_PHONE_STATE permission** in XML file. And added run time permissions **PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_PHONE_STATE**.
but I am getting the number empty. if its single SIM card I am able to get the device phone number.

Comment: this has nothing to do with dual USIM; later API might return an empty number.

Comment: i there any other way to get phone number in dual sim case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Comment: @PratapPenmetsa have you got the solution for getting phone number in react native??? if yes please tell me the proccess example code, i tried using DeviceInfo getPhoneNumber() but it return empty null and also i used  react-native-sim-data module but it also return null.

Comment: @RaikumarKhangembam no i didn't got any solution if its a dual sim we are not able to fetch mobile number.