# How to get SIM card phone number in android [If phone number is not stored in SIM] ..?

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions, upi

I want to fetch SIM phone number.

I have used **`TelephonyManager`** to get the same[`with READ_PHONE_STATE permission]` . I have tried for BSNL and JIO sim cards. I am getting phone number for JIO sim where as i am not getting for BSNL. Later i got to know that , API will give sim card number only if sim card contains Phone number.

I am using BHIM app and i tried to to UPI registration with BSNL sim and it works .
Here my question is how BHIM app is getting and how they are trying to get the phone number and i have checked they are also using [`READ_PHONE_STATE] permission` to get the number(if i dont give this permission app fails to proceed)

Any other method(Other than `READ_PHONE_STAE i.e telephonymanager`) using which we can get the phone numbers of device

Some people are suggesting to use HintRequest phone selector API but i am getting some run time errors 
below code i tried

```
private void requestHint() {
    HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
       .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
       .build();

    PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
        apiClient, hintRequest);
    startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
        RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2480307/7216511? maybe this can help

Comment: as i told i have tried this and i am getting null value because some sim cards dont hold mobile number