# Real Mobile Number Validation in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my Android app, how can I do real validation of mobile number?

> Like:-
>
> ```
> If(MobileNumber.isExists())
>     return true;
> else
>     return false;
> ```

Note:- No fake validation is required.

Can anyone do this, I am waiting for the right answer.

Comment: Are you trying to verify if the mobile number is a real phone number in the world? Or simply if the device you are on *has* a mobile number attached to it?

Comment: I believe your question has been asked and answered before.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone

Answer (score 0):

when you say real validation do you mean a phone number that already exists? Or a phone number that would be an appropriate value? I am unsure how to check if a phone number is in circulation but you could do a check to see if it is an appropriate length.

```
String mobileNumber;
int countryMobileLength;

if(mobileNumber.length() == countryMobileLength) {
    return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```