# How to retrieve SIM card IMSI in Android?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

```
public String getSubscriberId(){
    operator = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String IMSI = operator.getSubscriberId();
    return IMSI;
}

simID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    simIMSI = getSubscriberId().toString();

    if (simIMSI.equals("")){
        simID.setText("No SIM card detected!");
    }
    else{
        simID.setText(simIMSI.toString());
        SaveUniqueId(simIMSI.toString());
    }
```

I wish to retrieve the phone SIM card IMSI and display in a layout, I run the program using an emulator even though I know emulator does not have SIM card attached but it should have result like "No SIM card detected" right? But why I get error for this coding or is it something wrong in my "getSubscriberId()"?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033511/get-imei-code-or-and-mac-address-of-a-device

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String serviceName = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
TelephonyManager m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(serviceName);
```

Now let's start with actual source code to retrieve the information:-

```
public String findDeviceID() {
     String deviceID = null;
     String serviceName = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
     TelephonyManager m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(serviceName);
     int deviceType = m_telephonyManager.getPhoneType();
     switch (deviceType) {
           case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM):
           break;
  case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
  break;
  case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
  break;
          default:
         break;
     }
     deviceID = m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
     return deviceID;
}
```

For more details please refer this site http://ashnatechnologies.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-get-imei-on-android-devices.html

Comment: this code des not return IMSI as requested in the question. According to android docs, getdeviceId returns "IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones"

Answer (score 0):

You can visit this link  http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_getting_the_imsi_-_imei_sim-device_unique_ids-t446.html

use following code for IMSI

```
String imsi = android.os.SystemProperties.get(android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI);
```

Comment: but i got error on android.os.SystemProperties and android.telephony.TelephonyProperties... Should I import something?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

```
String myIMSI =
android.os.SystemProperties.get(android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI);
```