# Identifying the leaked private informations by inspecting smali code of Android application

Tags: android, security, reverse-engineering, smali

I'm trying to detect the leakage of private information by inspecting the smali code of Android applications. My strategy so far is.. searching the code that substitutes a personal information (e.g. IMEI, phone number) into a variable, then trace that variable until the point where it's sent to the internet or where it's not used anymore.

Are there any nice tools for doing this?

I've tried

- apkinspector (http://code.google.com/p/apkinspector/)
- androguard (http://code.google.com/p/androguard/)
- androwarn (https://github.com/maaaaz/androwarn)

, but none of these are likely to be able to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

unpack classes.dex, use dex2jar and inspect with jd-gui, it's somehow simpler, if jd-gui doesn't crash

you can also search for calls to functions needed to obtain some info, like imei [How to get the device's IMEI/ESN programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972381/how-to-programmatically-get-the-devices-imei-esn-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
But I want to do with smali code, because some information could be lost while converting classes.dex into java source code.

Comment: make a simple app that calls android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(), then apktool d the.apk then open the smali e search for invoke-virtual/invoke-direct call, you will have a pattern that gets imei in smali