# The android app interrupts its own installation

Tags: android, installation, application-design

I am making an android app and want it to get installed on only one particular device. What I want is that the installation of app should get interrupted whenever it is detected to be a device other than the one meant.

Comment: so the particular device, is a custom rom?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the manifest instead to define which devices you wish to support .
Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot interrupt the installation process.

An alternative solution would be checking the device's IMEI at startup, and if it doesn't match the IMEI of your device, exit the app immediately.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1972404/1615903) about getting the IMEI for guidance.